# Facing a high ANR rate in android 13 devices

Tags: android, crashlytics, android-sdk-tools, android-anr-dialog, android-13

[image]

I have a critical issue in my Android application. I am facing a high ANR (Application Not Responding) rate, which is occurring exclusively on Android version 13 devices. Despite exhaustive attempts, I have been unable to reproduce the ANR consistently or determine its root cause.

I'm getting this stack trace from Firebase crashlytics

```
    main (native):tid=1 systid=13180 
    #00 pc 0x501b0 libc.so (syscall + 32) (BuildId: 8cdfaa872c9e7191f6ce7a82d62dbc4b)
    #01 pc 0x54e7c libc.so (__futex_wait_ex(void volatile*, bool, int, bool, timespec const*) + 148) (BuildId: 8cdfaa872c9e7191f6ce7a82d62dbc4b)
    #02 pc 0xbb2bc libc.so (pthread_cond_wait + 80) (BuildId: 8cdfaa872c9e7191f6ce7a82d62dbc4b)
    #03 pc 0x284f3c libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::drawFrame() + 360) (BuildId: 56d31f3aab59c6c0ed6699bc4a8c8848)
           at android.graphics.HardwareRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native method)
           at android.graphics.HardwareRenderer.syncAndDrawFrame(HardwareRenderer.java:457)
           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:866)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:5120)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4819)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:4014)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2606)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9773)
           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1480)
           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1488)
           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1111)
           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1016)
           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1463)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:223)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:324)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8631)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1061)
```

I have optimized my code, updated all dependencies using the project, also upgrade AGP to v7.4.2. But nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be a little more specific.
Do you use Google ads in the app and what formats (banner, interstitial...)?
Do you use animations in the app, like `ViewCompat.animate(View)` or similar, and do you use hardware acceleration, like `View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE`, `ViewPropertyAnimator.withLayer()`, etc.? Are you using some audio player in combination with one of these instances?

I have the same problems only on API 33 and I am currently working on a solution. Due to the content of these ARNs, it is impossible to know precisely what causes this very unpleasant event for users. If I find the reasons, I will write here, and you answer the above questions. Thank you.
Greetings.

Comment: I have used Lottie Animation and ObjectAnimator.
And also I have added 'android:hardwareAccelerated="true"' property in the manifest file.

Comment: Good, but you need to ask what you are animating, in which parent container it is, when the animation starts and how often you call it. If you use ScrollView, there are certain problems in Android 13 (API 33) with memory leaks in the animations of its child elements. I have a big problem with these happenings, and I'm currently working on a solution. I'll get back to you in a day or two with a full answer, if I can get this resolved.